# The simple way to get int array from System.in in Java

Tags: java, arrays, input, int, system

The user types in System.in this

```
1 2 3 4 44 50 and so on
```

I need to get int array from it, so my solution is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tempString = in.nextLine();
        int tempArray[] = tempString.split(" ");
        result[] = tempArray(tempArray.length);

        for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the code?

Comment: Your code doesn't pass compilation - `tempArray` should be a String array, not an int array. And `tempArray(tempArray.length)` also doesn't pass compilation.

Answer (score 6):

With `Stream`s it can be done in a single line:

```
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> integersList = Stream.of("1 2 3 4 44 50".split(" "))
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also it can be usefull to remove redundant spaces

```
List<Integer> integersList = Stream
        .of("1 2 3 4 44 50".trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").split(" "))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer